# OpenCV perspective transform

Tags: python, opencv, perspective

I am currently working on creating a python software that tracks players on a soccer field. I got the player detection working with YoloV3 and was able to output quite a nice result with players centroids and boxes drawn. What i want to do now is translate the players position and project their centroids onto a png/jpg of a soccerfield. For this I inteded to use two arrays with refrence points one for the soccerfield-image and one for the source video. But my question now is how do I translate the coordinates of the centroids to the soccerfield image.

Similiar example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Cvn.png)
How the boxes and Markers are drawn:

```
def draw_labels_and_boxes(img, boxes, confidences, classids, idxs, colors, labels):
    # If there are any detections
    if len(idxs) > 0:
        for i in idxs.flatten():
            # Get the bounding box coordinates
            x, y = boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1]
            w, h = boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]

            # Draw the bounding box rectangle and label on the image
            cv.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 2)
            cv.drawMarker (img, (int(x + w / 2), int(y + h / 2)), (x, y), 0, 20, 3)
    return img
```

Boxes are generated like this:

```
def generate_boxes_confidences_classids(outs, height, width, tconf):
    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    classids = []

    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            # print (detection)
            # a = input('GO!')

            # Get the scores, classid, and the confidence of the prediction
            scores = detection[5:]
            classid = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[classid]

            # Consider only the predictions that are above a certain confidence level
            if confidence > tconf:
                # TODO Check detection
                box = detection[0:4] * np.array([width, height, width, height])
                centerX, centerY, bwidth, bheight = box.astype('int')

                # Using the center x, y coordinates to derive the top
                # and the left corner of the bounding box
                x = int(centerX - (bwidth / 2))
                y = int(centerY - (bheight / 2))

                # Append to list
                boxes.append([x, y, int(bwidth), int(bheight)])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                classids.append(classid)

    return boxes, confidences, classids
```

Comment: This is a very hard problem in CV as far as I know. You want to localize the real-world coordinates of moving objects from a single 2D image with a moving camera. I doubt you will find any openCV perceptive transformation function that does this for you. The current state-of-the art in this is probably some ML models that does 2D to 3D conversion. Not sure if this can be done any other way.

Comment: The camera would be stationary so a moving camera is not the problem in my case.

Comment: If the camera is stationary, how is the full filed captured at all times? At least according to your reference image, only a portion of the filed is in the frame. What happens when the players go out of the area?

Comment: It is only required for my project that half of the court is captured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a stationary camera,

- Find the coordinates of the four corners of the field.
- Find the corresponding four corners in the top-view image that you want to create.
- Find a homography matrix using these two sets of points. You can use OpenCV's `findHomography` for this.
- Transform all the centroids using this homography matrix and that should give you your coordinates in the new image space. You can use `warpPerspective` for doing this.

Comment: I tried this and i get the matrix but which function do I use to convert the points (x,y,w,h)?

Comment: Try using `warpPerspective`.

Comment: Figured it out now had to do some conversion to tuples to get single coordinates but worked out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Recently during COVID19 pandemic many developers have developed "social-distancing-monitoring-system". There a few of them also developed "Bird's Eye View" of the system. Your problem is just similar. As external links are not accepted here, so I am not able to post the exact link(s). Please check their codes in GitHub.